# Place one of 2 Sitecore template fields into nested Repeater's Hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink, sitecore, repeater, sitecore7

I'm trying to get a HyperLink Control inside nested repeater to display either the "Item No" field value or the "Menu Title" field value of the current Sitecore template. One of these fields will exist on all the templates that are sorted through within the repeater. But the issue I am facing is getting the code behind's ItemDataBound function to find the Hyperlink control. So far, the code keeps saying that it doesn't exist.

Here is the Repeater:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="ProductCategories" runat="server" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item" Visible="true" OnItemDataBound="ProductCategories_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="left-nav-section clearfix">
                <div class="left-nav-section-arrow clearfix"></div>
                <a class="left-nav-sub-section-title" href="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Item) %>" runat="server">
                    <%# Item.Fields["Menu Title"].Value %>
                </a>
                <div class="the-tiers">
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="CategoriesRepeater" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="ItemURL" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Item) %>"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And here is the ItemDataBound event for that repeater:

```
protected void ProductCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var catItem = e.Item.DataItem as Item;

        Repeater categoriesRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("CategoriesRepeater") as Repeater;
        var catProducts = catItem.GetChildren();

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            HyperLink itemLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("ItemURL");
            foreach (Item catProduct in catProducts)
            {
                if (catProduct.TemplateID.ToString() == productListingTemplateID.ToString())
                {
                    itemLink.Text = catProduct.Fields["Menu Title"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    itemLink.Text = catProduct.Fields["Item No"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
        if (catProducts.ToList().Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        categoriesRepeater.DataSource = catProducts;
        categoriesRepeater.DataBind();
    }
```

And here is the error that appears when I try to set the text property of the Hyperlink:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting for a while, this is what I came up with and it seems to work:

```
    protected void ProductCategories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var catItem = e.Item.DataItem as Item;

        Repeater categoriesRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("CategoriesRepeater") as Repeater;
        var catProducts = catItem.GetChildren();

        categoriesRepeater.DataSource = catProducts;
        categoriesRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Categories_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var catItem = e.Item.DataItem as Item;

        HyperLink itemLink = e.Item.FindControl("ItemURL") as HyperLink;

            if (catItem.Fields["Item No"] != null)
            {
                itemLink.Text = catItem.Fields["Item No"].ToString() + "<br />";
            }
            else
            {
                itemLink.Text = catItem.Fields["Menu Title"].ToString() + "<br />";
            }
     }


     <asp:Repeater ID="ProductCategories" runat="server" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item" Visible="true" OnItemDataBound="ProductCategories_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="left-nav-section clearfix">
                <div class="left-nav-section-arrow clearfix"></div>
                <a class="left-nav-sub-section-title" href="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Item) %>" runat="server">
                    <%# Item.Fields["Menu Title"].Value %>
                </a>
                <div class="the-tiers">
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="CategoriesRepeater" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item" OnItemDataBound="Categories_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="ItemURL" CssClass="left-nav-sub-tier" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Item) %>"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Not sure if it's the best idea ever, but it works. I'm still curious as to whether or not there is a better approach so additional solutions are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following syntax:

```
        foreach (Item catProduct in catProducts)
        {
            if (catProduct.TemplateID.ToString() == productListingTemplateID.ToString())
            {
                itemLink.Text = catProduct["Menu Title"];

                .. Use the same syntax for Item No..
            }

          ....
```

You can reference the field value using an indexer on the item if it is a string. That way you will not get Object Reference Errors - just an empty string.

In the code you were using you were trying to convert a Field into a string though it way work and give you the value it's safer and less code to use the indexer.

You can use the Fields property for more complex fields like a Multilist Field.